# Tkinter textbox not clickable when window first opened

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So when I first open the window, the everything else is fine, I can click the buttons and all but when I try to click the textbox and type something inside, the cursor does not appear and I can't type anything.
However, if I switch to any other window(literally anything from chrome to notepad) and switch back, I'm able to normally type inside the textbox.

I'm not sure how to solve this. Could anyone help me? My Python version is 3.8.0.

Here's part of my code and 'top' is my tkinter window's variable name. inputtxt1 and inputtxt2 is the textboxes I am having a problem with.

```
load_txt.set("analyze")
a_bt = Button(top, text = "analyze", command = _analyze_)
a_bt.config(textvariable=load_txt)
a_bt.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='E')
dir_bt = Button(top, text = "change dir", command = ch_dir)
dir_bt.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='W')
save_button['command'] = save_change
save_button.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='E')
top.geometry("600x1000")
top.resizable(width = True, height = True)

Label(top, text = "start_slab").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E')     
inputtxt1 = Text(top, height = 1, width = 5, state='normal')
inputtxt1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='E')

Label(top, text = "end_slab").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E')
inputtxt2 = Text(top, height = 1, width = 5, state='normal')
inputtxt2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E')

avg_bt = Button(top, text = "avg", command = show_avg)
prev_bt = Button(top, text = "prev", command = show_prev)
next_bt = Button(top, text = "next", command = show_next)
#panel.pack()

dir_name = askdirectory()

top.bind("<Return>", analyze)

top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

top.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

===========Edit===========

Here is a short working version of the code

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Text

frame_idx = 0
dir_name = None

top = Tk()
save_button = Button(top, text = "save images")

a_bt = Button(top, text = "analyze")
a_bt.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='E')
dir_bt = Button(top, text = "change dir")
dir_bt.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='W')
save_button.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='E')
top.geometry("600x1000")
top.resizable(width = True, height = True)

Label(top, text = "start_slab").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E')     
inputtxt1 = Text(top, height = 1, width = 5, state='normal')
inputtxt1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='E')

Label(top, text = "end_slab").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E')
inputtxt2 = Text(top, height = 1, width = 5, state='normal')
inputtxt2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E')

dir_name = askdirectory()


top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

top.mainloop()
```

It seems that when I don't have the askdirectory function, this does not become a problem but if I do, the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you post a minimalistic working example of your code?

Comment: @TheLizzard I edited the question! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `top.update()` or `top.update_idletasks()` just before `dir_name = askdirectory()`. I think that the `askdirectory` interferes with the entries so they stop handling events until they are redrawn on the screen (when you refocus the window). That might be a tcl bug? I have no idea how tcl handles events when `askdirectory` is called.